# Why does my PHP Code not allow me to save an unchecked Custom Checkbox, in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-fields

I am working on a WordPress website, with WooCommerce functionality.

I have created a Custom Checkbox Field, which appears in the WooCommerce Product Dashboard.  To create the Checkbox, I entered the following code into the `functions.php` file:

```
function product_custom_fields_add(){

   global $post;

   $input_checkbox = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_engrave_text_option', true );
   if( empty( $input_checkbox ) || $input_checkbox == 'no' ) $input_checkbox = '';

    echo '<div class="product_custom_field">';

    woocommerce_wp_checkbox(
        array(
            'id'        => '_engrave_text_option',
            'desc'      =>  __('set custom Engrave text field', 'woocommerce'),
            'label'     => __('Display custom Engrave text field', 'woocommerce'),
            'desc_tip'  => 'true',
            'value'     => $input_checkbox
        )
    );
    echo '</div>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_advanced', 'product_custom_fields_add');
```

To save the inputted values, I entered the following code, into the `functions.php` file:

```
function woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save($post_id){
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['_engrave_text_option'] ) )
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_engrave_text_option', esc_attr( $_POST['_engrave_text_option'] ));
}
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save');
```

The Checkbox successfully appears in the Product Dashboard and allows me to successfully select the Checkbox and Save.  The problem arises when I then go to Uncheck the Checkbox.  For some reason, when I Uncheck and then proceed to save the page, the page simply reloads with the Checkbox still Checked.

Is anyone able to see what is wrong with the above code, which could be causing this bug?

Comment: You are only updating if the value is not empty. The value will not be sent at all if the Checkboxen is unchecked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is PHP related thing, unchecked checkbox is not included to POST data.
So you need to have some adjusted code for saving part:

```
  function woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save($post_id){               
            $_engrave_text_option = isset( $_POST['_engrave_text_option'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_engrave_text_option', $_engrave_text_option );       
 }

add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save');
```